# Black screen and garbled fps counter after upgrade to Cocos2D 2.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I was working on a game in Cocos2D 1.0 (based on the tutorials in Learning Cocos2D) and just upgraded to Cocos2D 2.0, following the official directions [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3amigrate_to_v2.0), making sure to delete the old cocos2d library and replace it completely with the new one.

The code produces no errors, but after showing the Cocos2D startup image, it gives me a black screen with a garbled image where the frame rate counter used to be.

[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/0w4n4VQ) (image saves as portrait, even though the simulator is in landscape)

I'm not quite sure where to look for the problem (this is my first Cocos2D project), so I'll start with some code from my AppDelegate.m and some corresponding debugger output.

Code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Init the window
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

// Init the View Controller
viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

//
// Create the CCGLView manually
//  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
//  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
//
//
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];

// attach the openglView to the director
[director setView:glView];
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
[director setDisplayStats:YES];


// make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
[viewController setView:glView];

//Required in iOS6, recommended in 4 and 5
[window setRootViewController:viewController];

// make the View Controller a child of the main window, needed for iOS 4 and 5
[window addSubview: viewController.view];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

// Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
// It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
// You can change anytime.
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];


// Removes the startup flicker
//[self removeStartupFlicker];

// Run the intro Scene
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: [Level1Scene node]];

return YES;
}
```

Debugger:

```
2013-06-14 12:46:01.181 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0
2013-06-14 12:46:01.184 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2013-06-14 12:46:06.964 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: OS version: 5.0 (0x05000000)
2013-06-14 12:46:06.965 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
2013-06-14 12:46:06.966 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
2013-06-14 12:46:06.966 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE
2013-06-14 12:46:06.968 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2013-06-14 12:46:06.968 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
2013-06-14 12:46:06.969 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2013-06-14 12:46:06.970 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2013-06-14 12:46:06.970 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2013-06-14 12:46:06.971 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2013-06-14 12:46:06.972 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2013-06-14 12:46:06.972 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
2013-06-14 12:46:06.973 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
[Switching to process 25610 thread 0x1e0f]
[Switching to process 25610 thread 0x207]
2013-06-14 12:50:38.990 CocosGame[25610:207] cocos2d: surface size: 480x320
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: I managed to solve this by replacing my template files AppDelegate.m, AppDelegate.h, and main.m with new versions from the cocos2d 2.0 templates. (I'd lent the book to a friend, so I didn't realize that code wasn't from the book.) Still running into trouble, but I will post as a separate question if I can't solve it. Thanks for looking in!

Comment: update the standard assets too, in particular fps-images.png now has -hd variants that you need to have in your project.

Comment: Thanks @LearnCocos2D! The fps-images files were mentioned in the migration guide, but nothing else outside of the libs folder was. Is there a particular folder or set of files that qualify as "standard assets"?

Comment: AS it turns out, I didn't solve this. The templates fixed the black screen, but I still have (slightly different-looking) garbled status labels when building for standard resolution. Retina looks fine. Here's a screenshot of the issue, with other layers removed to make it more visible: [http://imgur.com/BlzVOuO](http://imgur.com/BlzVOuO)

Comment: Oops. Just needed to Clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by replacing my AppDelegate.m, AppDelegate.h, and main.m with new versions from the cocos2d 2.0 templates. I'd built the original project from cocos2d 1.0 templates, and the architecture seems to have changed in ways the migration guide didn't cover in depth.

One Clean and Build, and things were working as they should.